# How to Get a Cell Content of DataGrid which is not Selected in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

[image] 
1. how to Calculate a Price Cell. 
 2. their is no record is selected.
 3. At end it show sum of price cell.

```
private void dataGrid1_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string s = dataGrid1.Columns[2].GetCellContent(e.Row).ToString();
           //give me a Null Reference Error

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please, read about data binding in WPF. Don't try to work with WPF controls in WinForms style. Ultimately this will lead you to problems.

Comment: @Khalid Plz check my answer, and if this doesnt solve your problem, then you can access the cell too. I will update accordingly.

Comment: i Change the control Data grid to List View which is a lot easy than data grid and my problem is solve. than for your help friend.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
   sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: I am working on WPF Controls Not Window Form this is not working in WPF C#. Thanks

Comment: The code is for WPF not Win forms. Are you using MVVM?

Answer (score 0):

`LoadingRow` event gives you the current `DataGridRow`, so you need to access the corresponding Item to that `DataGridRow`.

So, Change this

```
   string s = dataGrid1.Columns[2].GetCellContent(e.Row).ToString();
```

to something similar to :

```
   MyItem item = Dgrd.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(e.Row) as MyItem;
   if (item != null)
   {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.Name);
   }
```

or,

```
    MyItem i =  e.Row.DataContext as MyItem;        
    if (item != null)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.Sku);
    }
```